# Mac OS - hidden window not showing in Dock

Tags: macos, dock, ventura

I recently moved to Ventura 13.4 and noticed that when an application window (like a Safari window, a .pdf opened in Preview etc.) is hidden, it is not visible when right-clicking on the app in the dock. My old Mac didn't have this problem and I could not find any relevant option in settings to disable this behavior. Does anyone have solution for this?

When a window is hidden:

[image]

When a window is not hidden:

[image]